# Why shoudl TSlint be executed after Typescript files is compiled?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, lint, tslint

According to the official TSLint, TSLint should executed only after the Typescript code is compiled. What is the reason behind this?

The official TSLint doc: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/

Comment: Where its written, I'm not able to find any such thing on url mentioned.

Comment: It says 'Please ensure that the TypeScript source files **compile correctly** before running the linter.'  my emphasis.  TSLint needs to parse the source code to give recommendations and its only going to be able to do that if its valid TypeScript that it can reason about - the  easiest way to verify this is to ensure the source code compiles.

Comment: A file that doesn't compile is *by definition* not going to pass the lint check. Linting is supposed to improve the code but that code has to already work - adding stuff like spaces around operators wouldn't really improve code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Additional information: TSLint uses the compiler to create the compiler's internal representation of the program and uses that for some rules.  Rules uses this representation as it can be easier to reason about than the raw source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TSLint runs against a parsed AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) that it receives from TypeScript. If the AST it receives from TypeScript has errors, its rules' logic might make some incorrect assumptions.

Defining a few of those terms:

- AST: Tree-like representation of your code that the linter will analyze. You can play around with [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net) to see what this looks like; it's pretty nifty!
- Syntax errors: if you write code such as `led foo = "bar";` *(`led` instead of `let`)*. TypeScript will create a different representation of your code than you might expect.
- Semantic errors: if you write code that has no syntax errors but the type checker finds issues with, such as `let foo: number = "bar";`.

TSLint has an issue open to discuss whether it shouldn't bother checking code that has syntax or semantic errors: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3808

Two additional points in favor of not running TSLint on invalid source files:

- A lot of people have trouble differentiating between TS and TSLint errors, so it can be confusing when an invalid file results in a *lot* of lint errors
- TS code that doesn't compile tends to have different linting issues after it gets fixed, so it's a bit of a waste to ask people to fix them along with the TS errors